# I want to build ruby object which is associated with 5 other tables asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, postgresql

I have a a table(let's call a) which is associated with 5 tables(b,c,d,e,f), when HTTP post request arrives, I want to build objects b,c,d,e,f on different threads and then save object of 'a' on main thread.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to build the objects in different threads?

Comment: Why with threads? This is Rails. That's usually completely unnecessary. Any processing you need to do shouldn't take long enough to require threads, and if it does, consider pushing that work into a queue and using [ActiveJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Comment: Yes, my api call is taking 1.2ms and accepted latency is 600-700 ms, so I need to optimise it.
I need data of other tables to be serialised in json response so pushing in Sidekiq/Resque is not an option here,
@tadman

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is based on how you've explained it. Is it taking 1.2ms or 600ms? Database insertion is usually a function of how slow/loverloaded the database is, not a function of how many threads you're using to jam things into it.

Comment: Data is around 30K rows average on each column.